# Process gets killed when run using computer ip address

Tags: c#, process, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an executable file that I need to run. When I run it like this

```
\\11.22.33.44\pathtoexe\myprocess.exe or

\\localhost\pathtoexe\myprocess.exe
```

the Windows Server 2012 R2 machine where it is run on, kills it.

However, if i start up cmd as administrator and go to the folder where the exe exists, and run it from there, the process doesn't gets killed.

What do I do in C# to prevent my process get killed by Windows?
Can I prevent this changing some params in

```
ProcessStartInfo
```

object?

Comment: Your program likely tries to access files in the directory where it's located and can't deal with network paths.

Comment: The process is likely not being killed by Windows. It kills itself because it throws an exception.  You can't prevent that. Fix the executable.

Comment: Change your process to not require admin access.

Comment: A good place to start is to catch and log any exceptions that occur so you actually can see what the problem is.

Comment: if this is .NET Framework: the trust model assigns different trust based on the location; this *could* be related to that - you could try mapping a network share (f: or something) to the location, and execute it from there? (mapped network shares get more trust than arbitrary network locations)

Comment: What does this process? Does it requires admin level? In that case it certainly throws an exception and terminate... thus if you have access to the code, put a global try...catch and debug to see what happens and what is the villain, and find where.

Comment: The question is not clear. Are you running myprocess.exe from another application via the Process class or are you running it manually from command line?